# provide rows by priority in django

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following model in django:

```
class task(models.Model):
    admin = models.BooleanField()
    date = modesl.DateField()
```

I am trying to achieve a filter which provides me with a query_set that prioritize if admin = True

So assume I have these 3 rows :

```
admin = True , date = 01-01-2019
admin = False , date = 01-01-2019
admin = False , date = 02-02-2019
```

The output of the query set will be :

```
admin = True , date = 01-01-2019
admin = False , date = 02-02-2019
```

it should filter out the row with 01-01-2019 which admin=False because there is already an admin=True row which should take prioritization.

I could do it by fetching all and removing it from the query_set myself, but want to make sure there is no other way of doing it before.

Comment: Do you want just the first value with `admin = True`. Or to put it another way, if you had several rows with `admin=True` and the same date would you like to fetch all of them?

Comment: if there is admin = true and admin = false for the same date, never provide both and prioritize admin=True

Comment: You should capitalize the names of your models.  It makes it easy to distinguish between an instance of a model (which should be lowercase) and the model class itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than looping through the QuerySet and removing them yourself, one thing you could do is:

1. Fetch all the dates where admin is `True`
2. Fetch all the objects where either:
   i. admin is `True`
   ii. The date is not in part 1 (e.g. admin is `False`)

This can be achieved with the following:

```
from django.db.models import Q

true_dates = task.objects.filter(admin=True).values_list("date", flat=True)
results = task.objects.filter(Q(admin=True)|~Q(date__in=true_dates))
```

This will most likely be more efficient than looping through your results yourself.

Note that since querysets are 'lazy' (this means only evaluated when they absolutely have to be) this will result in just 1 db hit

Comment: You should always use [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) when you need to call `values_list`, so that you only hit the database once.  See my answer for details.

Comment: amazing!! Thanks :) I didn't know that

Comment: Honestly, neither did I until trying to fix your query ;)

Comment: @CalebGoodman it's totally useles - when you pass a queryset as argument for a `in__` clause, the ORM already turns it into a subquery. You would actually have to explicitely _force_ `true_dates` into a list to prevent this.

Comment: @Tim this will only issue on single db query - querysets are lazy.

Answer (score 1):

Tim's answer is close, but incomplete, because he doesn't use [`Subquery()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions).

This answer provides the same results, without having an additional query hit the database:

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, Q

dates = Task.objects.filter(admin=True)
tasks = Task.objects.filter(Q(admin=True) | ~Q(date__in=Subquery(dates.values('date')))
```

Comment: Although I think for `tasks` we want `admin=True` or date not in dates,

Comment: @Tim thanks for pointing that out, I didn't catch that before.

Comment: @CalebGoodman actually, querysets are not eval'd (no db query is issued) until you try to retrieve data, and the ORM __already__ do the RightThing when you pass a queryset as `in__` clause argument: it generates a subquery.